# How can I create new branch from default branch in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have the branch name `default` which is my production branch. Now I want to create development branch from there and work separate on it.

How can I do that without affecting my default branch

Comment: See [branch](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html) and [Working in a named branch](http://mercurial.selenic.com/guide/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commit or shelve all your current changes, then:

```
hg branch Name_Of_Branch
```

This will switch your working code to a branch called *Name_Of_Branch* - **N.B.** this branch will not exist in the local repository until you do a `hg commit` and will not exist for anybody else until you have done a `hg push`, *(or an accepted pull request to an administrator)*, and they have done `hg pull`.

Comment: i write a really long answer with out looking at the question correctly.

Comment: +1 is it possible to use `hg checkout -b Name_Of_Branch`?? is it work if in my code every `git` replace by `hg`

Comment: You forgot `hg commit`, because branch will not appear before commit in repo

Comment: You in hg can't check out a branch that doesn't exist yet - quite sensibly so you need to have a local copy of the code, branch it and check then commit and, (when ready to share), push the changes onto the new branch.  If your branch name already exists in the local copy of the repository you will switch to it otherwise you will create it.